# Widget options in Ubuntu?

Tags: gnome, themes, 18.04, widgets, screenlets

I did some search, and all I get are:

- Screenlets
- gDesklets
- Universal Applets
- Conky

Out of which **conky seems to be the most anticipated** but all of them seem to be deprecated.

[gdesklets died and universal applets arised which also lost it's development](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=936336)

[Screenlets went as far as 16.10 but that too is kinda buggy](https://www.fossmint.com/screenlets-easily-add-widgets-to-ubuntu-desktop/)

[There are some discussion threads, but they date back to 2008, 2010.](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1096909)

I'm currently using conky and it's working great with configurations from [DeviantArt](https://www.deviantart.com/). Also there's CoverGloobus as a *sincere* music widget(I'm not sure about it's development though).

Can someone who's been around for a while guide us *newcomers*?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu uses gdm3 nowadays and there it is called [gnome extensions](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Extensions). You can find them on the [extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org/). From the 1st link:

> **Extensions**
>
> The GNOME Shell extension design is designed to give a high degree of power to the parts of the GNOME interface managed by the shell, such as window management and application launching. It simply loads arbitrary JavaScript and CSS. This gives developers a way to make many kinds of changes and share those changes with others, without having to patch the original source code and recompile it, and somehow distribute the patched code.
>
> The extension system is a replacement for the "applets" or "widgets" system of GNOME 2. Extensions can add their own items to the top panel, but they can also do much more: adding a custom search provider, for instance. For more information, see [this post](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/desktop-devel-list/2009-April/msg00267.html).

Comment: I knew about shell extensions and I already use them, although I didn't know that `The extension system is a replacement for the "applets" or "widgets" system of GNOME 2`. So that means there isn't any likely development of widget-like things in the future, and it kind of answers all the loss in development that has happened. Would you be kind enough to also add if there are some widgets working(maybe show some light on CoverGloobus for 18.04)?

Comment: Suggest you contact its developer at https://launchpad.net/covergloobus  and the fact that Ubuntu has been wandering around in the wilderness with Wayland and Unity for years may account for the lack of the goodies which you seek.